# Getting an AJAX error when submitting to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a basic form where I submit the ID of a facebook friend and the php returns my name, my FB photo, my friend's name and my friend's fb photo. Here's my relevant code

**HTML**

```
<form name="input">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div class="row" id="graphArea"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    submitForm(formData);
});

function submitForm(formData){
$.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'graph.php',        
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 7000,
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#graphArea").load("graph.php");
        $(window).scrollTop($("#graphArea").offset().top);
        $("#graphArea").fadeIn(500);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("There was an error");          
    },              
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            

        $('form')[0].reset();
    }
});
```

**graph.php**

```
<?php
    require 'resources/plugin/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
    //..some facebook authentication stuff
    $friend = $_POST['name'];
    $basicInfo = $fb->api('me?fields=friends.uid(' . $friend . ').fields(first_name,name),first_name,name');
 ?>
<hr>
<br />
<div class="span2 offset2"><h3>
<?php
    echo $basicInfo['name'] . "</h3></div><div class=\"span2\">";
    echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/" . $user . "/picture?type=large'>";
    echo "</div><div class=\"span2\">";
    echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/" . $friend . "/picture?type=large'></div>";
    echo "<div class=\"span2\"><h3>" . $basicInfo['friends']['data'][0]['name'];
?>
</h3>
</div>
```

Everytime I submit the form, I get the error part where it alerts "There was an error". However looking through the Google Chrome Javascript Console and I click Network and then Preview, I see the result I want! This is my first time dealing with PHP and AJAX and I would appreciate all the help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Your ajax call says it's expecting `json`, but graph.php is returning HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call to `graph.php` includes `dataType: 'json'`, but `graph.php` appears to output an HTML fragment.  Additionally, your AJAX success handler makes another call to `graph.php` -- which is unnecessary since you just made a call to `graph.php` to submit the form.  You should instead take the HTML returned and inject it into the DOM:

```
$.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'graph.php',        
    data: formData,
    // REMOVED dataType
    cache: false,
    timeout: 7000,
    success: function(data) { 
        $("#graphArea").html(data);   // CHANGED
        $(window).scrollTop($("#graphArea").offset().top);
        $("#graphArea").fadeIn(500);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("There was an error");          
    },              
    complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {            

        $('form')[0].reset();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! I'm getting an error in the console that states: The requested URL /<hr><br was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2):

In your javascript ajax call you given as `dataType: 'json',` and from the `php` you returning the `html` this will throw the error. If you want the response to be in html, change the datatype to `html`.